# ldap query for group members

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to make an LDAP query, to get a list from all my groups/members. I can't figure out how can i do this. All my tries were unsuccesfull.

My "AD tree": mydomain.local/Mybusiness/Distribution Groups/ here are my groups

I tried with somethin' like this:

```
(objectCategory=user)
(memberOf=CN=Distribution Groups,OU=Mybusiness,DC=mydomain.local,DC=com)
```

I appreciate if somebody could help me to write an ldap query, which gives a list with my groups and the members of this groups.

Answer (score 15):

The query should be:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=Distribution Groups,OU=Mybusiness,DC=mydomain.local,DC=com))
```

You missed **&** and **()**

Comment: If I understand, this query will show all members that have the same `domain` as the group. What if I want to see **all** group members, regardless of `domain`?

Comment: @juan mellado I'm afraid I didn't catch you. Groups should be created under domain. here's an example: (&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=admins,DC=root,DC=com)) - this query will show all the members in admins groups, "CN=admins,DC=root,DC=com" is the DN of the group.

Answer (score 11):

Active Directory does not store the group membership on user objects.  It only stores the Member list on the group.  The tools show the group membership on user objects by doing queries for it.

How about:

(&(objectClass=group)(member=cn=my,ou=full,dc=domain))

(You forgot the (& ) bit in your example in the question as well).

Comment: im not familiar with AD and LDAP. I try to make this query as you mentioned, but the result is empty. what mean ou=full?

Comment: Replace the joking cn=my,ou=full,dc=domain value, with a REAL DN to the user of interest in your system.  My.Full.Domain in dot notation.

Answer (score 4):

The good way to get all the members from a group is to, make the DN of the group as the searchDN and pass the "member" as attribute to get in the search function. All of the members of the group can now be found by going through the attribute values returned by the search.
The filter can be made generic like (objectclass=*).

Comment: To elaborate on jwilleke's comment, by default AD won't list more than 1500 (1000 in old versions) components of a multivalued attribute like `member`, however of course many AD Groups have many more members than that. AD supports [ranged retrieval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa367017) to fetch all attributes from AD groups with > 1500 (or 1000) members.