# LDIF for group needed to use with PHP

Tags: php, centos7, openldap, ldap-query

Using CentOS 7.5, Apache 2.4.6. Running in a VM. No SSL.

I followed https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-ldap-on-centos-7/ and configured OpenLDAP.

I created users and used the ldap_bind($ds, $userid, $password) to check if a valid user & password exists.

Now I am trying to find if a user is a member of a particular group. For that, I looked at [ldap query for group members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825994/ldap-query-for-group-members) (among others)

I think that I am making a mistake in creating the group.

Should I create an organizationalRole, group or posixGroup? As the final objective is to check which users are authorized to use which applications and functions therein (add/update/delete/etc.) I would say that organizationalRole is the thing to make. At the moment, I used:

groups.ldif:

```
dn: cn=MyAppUsers,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany
objectClass: top
objectclass: posixGroup
cn: Authorized App1 Users
description: Users allowed to use App1
```

users.ldif:

```
dn: cn=MyAppUsers,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany
changetype: modify
add: memberUid
memberUid: cn=user1,ou=People,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany
memberUid: cn=user2,ou=People,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany
```

I tried different combinations of filters in ldap_search($ds,$basedn,$filter) but just can't seem to find the correct one. So, I'm thinking that it's not the query which is wrong, but the manner in which the group was created.

Comment: As per the second link in my post, this user and group membership would then be validated by PHP. The PHP code that I am usiing to check group membership is as per that link. My code fails to return the group, hence, I added this tag. Also, as far as I understand, the type of group/role depends on where it is used; in my case, PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both LDIF above are actually updating the same entry.
The first one creates it, the second one adds members to the group. However the users added are referenced by Distinguished Names (DN) and the memberUID just expects a User Id.
So they should be:

```
memberUid: user1
memberUid: user2
```

Then you can check if a user is part of the group with

```
ldap_search($ds, "cn=MyAppUsers,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany", "(memberUid=user1)")
```

Or you can search for all groups the user is part of with

```
ldap_search($ds, "dc=mydept,dc=mycompany", "(&(objectclass=posixGroup)(memberUid=user1))")
```

Comment: As easy as that, eh? Yes, it worked great. Thanks! So, does every user I create must have a uid, or can this work also: ldap_search($ds, "...", "(cn=user1)")

Comment: What if I have two similar users? dn: uid=joe,ou=People,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany and dn: uid=joe,ou=People,dc=otherdept,dc=mycompany? I assume that uid's must be unique? Can I not have uid's at all, something like dn: cn=joe,ou=People,dc=mydept,dc=mycompany

Comment: If you want to use Posix Groups, then yes, all users must have uid, and they must be unique (otherwise your OS security may be compromised. uid = login id).

Comment: Ludovic, no. I don't have to use posixgroups. Am not very clear on what they are. I'm using them as the sample used them. The ldap users would not be OS users; i.e. would only be used for authentication via PHP. So, what else can I use? A rolegroup? If you have a sample ldif for defining those, kindly share.  How would I then check from PHP if a user exists within a rolegroup?

Comment: The standard groups are "groupOfNames" where members are not referred to by cn or uid but by their whole DN, i.e. `member=cn=Joe,ou=People,dc=mydept,dc=myCompany`